# add condition in my linear regression model in SAS

Tags: model, sas, linear-regression

I am a beginner of SAS. I am currently doing a linear model but I stuck at fitting the model. Initially, I need to split the data into two parts first.

Here is my code to cut the data into 2 parts, T is explanatory data then C is the response.

```
data mydata;
set rawdata;
if T < 10 then Cbelow = C;
else Cabove= C;
run;
```

Then I am doing the model as I wanna to check the linear regression when T <10 and T>= 10. Then I used the data I splitted just now. Then my code is below:

```
proc reg data= mydata;
 if T<10 then model Cbelow=T;
 else model Cabove=T
run;
```

I got errors when I run the above code. I couldn't figure out why. Can anyone help me with issue ? Any help would be very apperaciated. 
Many Thanks in advance !

Here is error :

```
 proc reg data= mydata;
157
158  if T<10 then model Cbelow=T;
     --
     180
NOTE: The previous statement has been deleted.
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
159
160  else model Cabove=T
     ----
     180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
161
162  run;
NOTE: The previous statement has been deleted
```

Comment: Yeah I just add into question. sorry for that.

Comment: You really should look at the documentation for proc reg before moving forward.  The documentation for SAS is very detailed and tells you what kinds of statements are legal in what proc.

Comment: I think you need to think about what it is your trying to model. If you want two separate regressions, that's easy. Just use a `where` statement to select the observations you want. If you want a single regression allowing for a different intercept above and below `T = 10`, then you want to model `C = T above` where `above` is a dummy indicating `T > 10`. if you want to allow the slope to change at `t = 10`, then you interact `above` with `T` and include that in your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joe says, you should look in the documentation.  That said, I will read between the lines and help you out here.

If you are looking for 2 separate regressions, no pooled or mixed effects, etc, then add a classification variable and use the `BY` statement in `PROC REG`.

```
data mydata;
set rawdata;
if T < 10 then High_Low ="LOW";
else High_Low = "High";
run;

proc sort data=mydata;
by high_low;
run;

proc reg data=mydata;
by high_low;
model C=T;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am very grateful. I wish I could look in the document but I am running out of time. Actually this is a project I was supposed to do R code and my groupmate was in charge of SAS. She just told me she couldn't do SAS two days before the deadline so I have to pick up where she left in the last mintutes.Indeed, I really want to study all fundamental code for SAS but I have no time. Anyway, thanks for the sincere help, you are very kind.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it and up-vote.  If there is something else, let us know.